# How can I install an apt-get/pip package for use by a particular Python version?

Tags: apt, python, version, pip

OS Linux Mint 18.3. Based on Ubuntu Xenial.

This gives "Python 3.5.2" as its installed version. I learnt the hard way that it's not good to try and upgrade Python in a Ubuntu OS as apparently it's used by the system components.

But I wanted to use Python 3.6, so I installed it, and if I want to run it I can just go `Python3.6 xxx`. I've also set up Eclipse to work with it.

Now I want to use PyQT (GUI module), so I found out that you go:

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev-tools
```

A test program then worked fine running in a Terminal (using "python3 test.py" i.e. the system's Python), but failed when I went "python3.6 test.py": the modules were obviously not available for the 3.6 version. It also failed in the Eclipse project where I've set the version as 3.6.

So then I wondered how I might install a version which would be visible to 3.6. I wondered if `pip` might do the job. So I went:

```
python3.6 -m pip install python-qt4
```

and then

```
python3.6 -m pip install pyqt5-dev-tools
```

These both failed, giving the same message (substituting in "pyqt5-dev-tools" obviously):

```
mike@M17A ~/software projects/eclipse-workspace/PyLookup2019-09/src/core $  python3.6 -m pip install python-qt4
Collecting python-qt4
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-qt4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-qt4
```

How do I make my 3.6 version able to use PyQt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pip` command wants the Python package name, not the Ubuntu package name.

Try the command `python3.6 -m pip install PyQt5`

You should be able to see available related packages with `python3.6 -m pip search pyqt`

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications...